# Time difference in compilation?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

I have two c++ programs named example.cpp (takes two numbers and outputs their sum) in two directories: `my home directory` and inside a folder in `var/www/myfolder`.

When I run the following command `g++ example.cpp` (command line) in both directories the time differs.
In the first case it takes `0.5sec` and in the second `0.072 sec`. Why so much difference??

I am using ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Is the source code the same?

Comment: GCC is huge. G++ is even bigger. And they have even bigger shared lib dependencies which only need to be loaded into memory for the first time you run the compilers.

Comment: does including more headers in one source be the reason ??

Comment: Yes. Headers are part of the source code, if one file includes more/different headers, then the source code is not the same.

Comment: Many random factor may lead to this. Time mesurement, system load, disk buffer, etc. Try compiling your program for a few times and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your home directory is not local to your machine and therefore reading and writing to it may entail network delays.